# Организация поиска в С++

Tags: access, c++

Всем привет. Подскажите как организовать поиск на С++, среда rad studio 2009.

Но форме имеется подключенная БД Access, которая показывает, определенные данные через DbGrid. Как мне сделать поиск по этой БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сконструируйте подходящий SQL-запрос, скажем, LIKE и выполните в [TADOQuery](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/ADOQuery_(C%2B%2B)):

```
ADOQuery = new TADOQuery(this);
ADOQuery->Connection = ADOConn;
ADOQuery->SQL->Add("SELECT ... WHERE ... LIKE ...");
ADOQuery->Prepared = true;

try {
    ADOQuery->Active = true;
}
catch (EADOError *e) {
}
```